# Colocar validação em Identity do Asp Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, asp.net-identity

Tentei localizar essa duvida no forum e não consegui encontrar. Tenho uma aplicação MVC Asp Net que utiliza para o login o Entity Framework com Identity. Meu cadastro de cliente funciona perfeitamente, mas não estou conseguindo validar dois campos: Username e Login. Tentei localizar onde eles são chamados, mas pelo o que li na net até agora, ele fica "encapsulado" e não consegui colocar as validações neles. GOstaria de colocar uma validação como essa neles:

```
[Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }
```

O problema é que não estou conseugindo encontrar Username e Login. Não consegui encontrar o AccountViewModels.cs que me indicaram na net. Alguem pode me ajudar por favor? Gostaria apenas de validar os campos de Username e Login para que não seja possivel salvar o cadastro com eles em branco, como não encontrei a localização deles, não consigo validar e a maneira mais facil que encontrei foi como informei no código acima.

Comment: se você salva ele certamente esta passando o valor para eles em sua action ... só dar um F12 em cima da classe.

Answer (score 0):

Para registrar um usuário, o identity no aspnet mvc 5 utiliza a classe **RegisterViewModel** que esta no arquivo **AccountViewModels.cs** dentro da pasta **Models**.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Esta é a classe recebe o email, a senha e a confirmação de senha da tela de registro. Aqui você pode customizar as validações a vontade.

Comment: Tentei encontrar esse arquivo AccountViewModels.cs  no meu projeto na pasta Models e não encontrei. Sabe se ele pode ter outro nome? Procurei em todo o projeto aqui e não localizei esse arquivo da Model nem a classe RegisterViewModel

Comment: Qual versão do .net esta usando? Esta usando o identity que tem no template?

Comment: seria essa  versão, certo? <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />

Comment: Ta bem estranho não ter esses arquivos. Pode subir uma screenshot das pastas de model e controller do seu projeto para eu ver como esta?

Comment: subi a imagem das pastas aqui https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/pastas-jpg--3

Comment: Pelos seus arquivos vc nao ta usando o identity que vem no template do aspnet mvc 5. Voce implementou seu proprio sistema de login?

Comment: Isso, na verdade segui um curso que ensinava afazer esse sistema de login. O curso já encerrou e vi que ficaram alguns pontos pendentes, como essas validações e não estou mais conseguindo entrar em contato com eles.

Comment: Então pra responder sua pergunta teria que ter acesso ao seu codigo de registro de usuário (controller e viewmodel) pra poder te ajudar. Usando o identity padrão do aspnet mvc a resposta é a que dei mesmo.